# Using regex in python to remove double quotes with exclusions

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to remove specific double quotes from text using regular expression in python. I would like to leave only those double quotes which indicate an inch. So this would mean leave any double quote following a number.

`txt = 'measurement 1/2" and 3" "remove" end" a " multiple"""`

Expected output:
`measurement 1/2" and 3" remove end a multiple`

This is the closest I've got.

`re.sub(r'[^(?!\d+/\d+")]"+', '', txt)`

Comment: `txt` isn't a valid string, no?

Comment: What about `ABC2DEF3"` cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
(?<!\d)"+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uP2nPt/1/).

---

Your original expression

```
[^(?!\d+/\d+")]
```

basically meant not `(`, `?`, `!`, etc.

---

Alternatively, you could use the newer `regex` module with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
import regex as re

junk = '''measurement 1/2" and 3" "remove" end" a " multiple"""
ABC2DEF3"'''

rx = re.compile(r'\b\d(?:/\d+)?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"+')

cleaned = rx.sub('', junk)
print(cleaned)
```

Which would yield

```
measurement 1/2" and 3" remove end a  multiple
ABC2DEF3
```

Comment: You do not need the PyPi regex module here, `re.sub(r'\b(\d+(?:/\d+)?")|"+', r'\1', text)` will suffice with `re` (this is for Python 3.5+).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew this actually works the best. I hadn't considered the case with abcdef3 and this catches that as well!